# How to add comment to squeak class?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I'm following Squeak by example
http://squeakbyexample.org/

I'm stuck with

"Type a class comment for SBECell and accept it; you can always improve it
later."

I typed a comment but I can see no way to accept it ! Alt-click doesn't work as usual (I'm on Windows). I think Smalltalk IDE is weird that may explain why I did give up many times no offense meant but tutorial should then be more explicit for complete newbies like me !

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to edit a class comment in the Squeak Browser click on the **?** button between the *instance* and *class* buttons.

I'm sorry you're having difficulties learning Squeak. You may have more luck following the instructions in [Pharo by Example](http://pharobyexample.org/). I'm not sure what's the current state of affairs but I've heard the [Pharo](http://www.pharo-project.org) version of the book is more up to date than the Squeak version.

Comment: Thanks it works - weird the tutorial didn't mention the "?" button: how am I suppoed to guess that :). Have glanced at Pharo tut seems good for a starter will try.